# Vertical scrollview is not working in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, scroll

in below code scrollview is not working all are the labelfields in this form whenever i am adding a buttonfield in above code its scrolling but when i remove that it's  not working so my question is how to scroll a screen when there is only label fields in the form?

```
final VerticalFieldManager mainreportfractionsodiumvfm = new VerticalFieldManager(
            Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

    // For action bar
    final HorizontalFieldManager vfm_r = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
        // Applying background color for that Manager
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0Xde3f39);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }

        // Placing the Fields

        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

            setPositionChild(getField(0), 0, 0);
            layoutChild(getField(0), getField(0).getPreferredWidth(),
                    getField(0).getPreferredHeight());

            setPositionChild(getField(1), Display.getWidth() / 2
                    - getField(1).getPreferredWidth() / 2, 0);
            layoutChild(getField(1), getField(1).getPreferredWidth(),
                    getField(1).getPreferredHeight());

            setPositionChild(getField(2), Display.getWidth()
                    - getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 0);
            layoutChild(getField(2), getField(2).getPreferredWidth(),
                    getField(2).getPreferredHeight());

            setExtent(width, 35);
        }

    };

    final ButtonField bmpfield1 = new ButtonField("menu");
    // To display Home icon

    final Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("home.png");
    BitmapField bmpfield2 = new BitmapField(bmp2, Field.FOCUSABLE
            | Field.FIELD_RIGHT);

    // To display Title

    final VerticalFieldManager hfm_mainlbltext = new VerticalFieldManager(
            FIELD_HCENTER);
    LabelField lbl = new LabelField("Body Surface Area",
            Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    LabelField lbl1 = new LabelField("Report", Field.FIELD_VCENTER);

    lbl.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
    lbl1.setFont(lbl1.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
    // setMargin(int top, int right, int bottom, int left)
    lbl1.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 50);
    hfm_mainlbltext.add(lbl);
    hfm_mainlbltext.add(lbl1);

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // fields
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    LabelField lbltxt1 = new LabelField(
            "A Fractional Excretion of Sodium (FENa)", FIELD_HCENTER) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0xde3f39);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt1.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt1.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt2 = new LabelField(
            "1% suggests pre-renal disease, while > 1% is suggestive of acute tubular necrosis (ATN).",
            FIELD_HCENTER) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x6d6e76);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt2.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt2.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    VerticalFieldManager hfm8 = new VerticalFieldManager();
    HorizontalFieldManager hfmresult = new HorizontalFieldManager();

    hfm8.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);

    final LabelField lblresulttext1 = new LabelField("Result :") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x6d6e76);

            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    final LabelField lblresulttext2 = new LabelField(
            "Fraction Excreation of Sodium") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x6d6e76);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    final LabelField lblresulttext3 = new LabelField("for this patient is") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x6d6e76);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    final LabelField lblresultcal = new LabelField("") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x0AFF0A);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    hfmresult.add(lblresulttext1);
    hfmresult.add(lblresulttext2);
    hfmresult.add(lblresulttext3);
    // setMargin(top,right,bottom,left)
    lblresulttext2.setMargin(5, 0, 0, 0);

    lblresulttext1.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 27));
    lblresulttext2.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
    lblresultcal.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 26));

    hfm8.add(hfmresult);
    hfm8.add(lblresultcal);

    // to store the Bitmap
    final HorizontalFieldManager hfmforbitmap = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            FIELD_HCENTER);
    Bitmap objimage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bar.png");

    // to display the Bitmap
    hfmforbitmap.add(new BitmapField(objimage));

    LabelField lbltxt3 = new LabelField(
            "Fractional Exceretion of Sodium formula ", FIELD_HCENTER) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0Xde3f39);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt3.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt3.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt4 = new LabelField(
            "UNa X Pcreat / Ucreat X PNa * 100%", FIELD_HCENTER) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x6d6e76);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt4.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt4.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt5 = new LabelField("Where") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x000000);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt5.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt5.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt6 = new LabelField("UNa = Urine sodium") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x000000);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt6.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt6.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt7 = new LabelField("Pcreat = Plasma creatinine") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x000000);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt7.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt7.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt8 = new LabelField("Ucreat = Urine creatinine") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x000000);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt8.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt8.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    LabelField lbltxt9 = new LabelField("PNa = Plasma sodium") {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x000000);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    lbltxt9.setPadding(0, 5, 5, 5);
    lbltxt9.setFont(lbl.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 15));

    ButtonField btn = new ButtonField("btn");

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////// addding all //
    // fields here

    final HorizontalFieldManager hfm_main = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

    final VerticalFieldManager vfm_l = new VerticalFieldManager() {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(280, maxHeight);
            setExtent(280, maxHeight);
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            // Clears the entire graphic area to the current background
            g.clear();
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    vfm_l.add(new LabelField("sliding pannel"));
    vfm_r.add(bmpfield1);
    vfm_r.add(hfm_mainlbltext);
    vfm_r.add(bmpfield2);

    // all layouts are added here in vertical scroll field

    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(vfm_r);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt1);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt2);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(hfm8);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(hfmforbitmap);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt3);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt4);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt5);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt6);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt7);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt8);
    mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(lbltxt9);
    // mainreportfractionsodiumvfm.add(btn);
    hfm_main.add(mainreportfractionsodiumvfm);
    add(hfm_main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you need to have focusable `Fields` on your `Manager` in order for it to scroll.

Its been a while since I did this hack, but can you not set some of your `LabelFields` to get focus? I think this involves creating your own custom `LabelField` and overriding method `isFocusable()` to return `true`.

---

**Edit:** Peter Strange is correct - pls use the `NullField` as he suggests.

Comment: no i can't make labelfields focusable.I think i am going to use u r second option thanks for quick reply @Richard Le Mesurier

Comment: Rather than an invisible Button, I use NullField where I need a non display focusable Field like this.  Note that in OS 6.0 and above, my experience is that even non focusable Fields will scroll, so this trick is only need for OS 5.0 and below.

Comment: thx @PeterStrange - yes I'm a bit rusty on the BB these days - answer updated